# how to pass the name attribute insted of id in mongoid?

Tags: overriding, mongoid

i am using mongoid database, i am trying to override the id attribute in url to name, but i am getting error

my model is like this

```
class Product

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  field :price, type: BigDecimal

  field :released_on, type: Date

  field :_id, type: String, default: -> { name.to_s.parameterize }

  validates_presence_of :name

  embeds_many :reviews

end
```

Comment: field :_id, type: String, default: -> { name.to_s.parameterize }

Comment: i added this line of code to model

Comment: can someone help me to pass name in place of id in url

Comment: in mongoid database

Comment: you wanted to store name in `_id` field in database?